# How to make ActivityOptions like it's lifetime dynamic in the workflow

Tags: java, cadence-workflow

Since my activity workload could be diffrent dramatically we can not use a fixed scheduleToCloseTimeoutSeconds

In the workerImpl's constructor I new the stubs for our activities which are going to be used in the workflowmethods. but the problem is that the adviced method of registering the workflow is by type:
`registerWorkflowImplementationTypes`
which only accepts a class. so there is no way to pass in the options like lifetime to the workflow which could be used to make the acitivityOptions dynamic.

So is what I am trying to achieve doing an antipattern to the Cadense? 
If not, what is the correct way of doing it? probably workflow factory methods should be used, but the docs indicate those are to be used for unit test and mocking mostly and looks like using the `registerWorkflowImplementationTypes` is the prefered method.

Answer (score 0):

The Cadence workflow implementation code [must be deterministic](https://cadenceworkflow.io/docs/06_javaclient/03_implementing_workflows#workflow-implementation-constraints). One way to break determinism is to directly rely on a configuration that can change during a workflow execution.

The standard way to solve this problem is to pass the configuration parameters to a workflow method as an argument or load them using an activity. Usually a [local activity](https://github.com/uber/cadence-java-client/blob/d65c3e5ff2fcbdcf20ad980b798ee15bb7632f83/src/main/java/com/uber/cadence/workflow/Workflow.java#L411) which is more efficient is used for this purpose.